# How to disable line wrap in a terminal?

Tags: terminal

I need to view large logs files using a bash shell. I was using `less` to open the files, but since the lines are too lengthy there is some kind of line/word wrapping going on.

Since the files are Log4J logs, and there is a pattern in the beginning of each line, having lines wrapped makes it difficult to analyze the output, so I started using `less -S` which chops long lines.

But now I need to use `tail -f`, and it also line wraps the output. Is it possible to disable line wrap in a bash shell for all the commands?

**Note:** there is an answer to a different question that mentions the escape sequence `echo -ne '\e[?7l'`, but it seems to not work on bash.

Comment: Note that this is unrelated to your choice of shell (bash), but it can depend on your choice of terminal (xterm, Terminal, gnome-terminal, konsole, …). See [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126)

Comment: As Gilles mentioned, it is a matter of the terminal emulator.  For example, in `screen`, there is a "wrap" command.  In `xterm`, there is a `-aw` option to prevent automatic line wraps.  Likely there are some X resources for other terminal emulators.  What emulator are you using?

Comment: I am using `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: @Arcege: Actually, it is `+aw` for `xterm` :) But, this solves the issue for **output** (e.g., on `ls -l` with a bunch on long Windows-ish names from TPB, it works fine), for **input**, when entering a command, you probably still want wrap (or, at least you don't want it the way it is now on `+aw`: try write beyond the "column border" and then backtrack for a huge GFX bug).

Comment: By the way, it seems neither `urxvt` nor `rxvt` can disable line wraps.

Comment: What about "| cut c1-200"?

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/questions/73443/how-to-stop-the-terminal-from-wrapping-lines | https://superuser.com/questions/188865/how-to-make-bash-not-to-wrap-output

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you actually need `tail -f` or would something like `less +F` do?  Since it sounds like you still want an interactive pager, it seems to me it would be much easier to stick with `less` than to reimplement one yourself.

A final note: have you considered `tail -f file | less`?

Comment: I made some experiences with `screen` and `xterm` as those emulators have options to prevent line wraps. But there is a big difference between truncating the line and hiding the tail of the line so we can view it if we want. Using `tail -f file | less -S` is not perfect as it seems to disable the `-f` but it is the best solution I found.

Comment: @Boris Marcos 's answer is perhaps better. It uses `less` directly.

Answer (score 82):

Try:

```
less -S +F filename
```

=

```
less --chop-long-lines +F filename
```

And then:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to stop tailing and now you can move left and right using cursor keys.
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to resume tailing
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>q</kbd> to quit

> less manual:   `+`      If a command line option begins with +, the remainder of that option is taken to be an initial command to less.

For example, `+F` tells less to scroll forward, and keep trying to read when the end of file is reached

Comment: This is great! Been having my terminal span two screens, but since I read this yesterday I just pipe the wide output to `less -S`. Also very useful on the laptop.

Answer (score 62):

Found a [good answer from superuser](https://superuser.com/a/600694/134634), that works out of the box for `gnome-terminal`, and probably for other terminals as well:

```
setterm -linewrap off
```

[image]

Comment: This is `setterm --linewrap off` for me using gnome-terminal with zsh on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: how do i scroll horizontally then?

Comment: You don't. This is just a simple method for reducing noise. Other answers here deal with horizontal scrolling but are more cumbersome. You could even pipe everything into Vim `| vim -`.

Comment: If this is in a script, how can I reset the linewrap option off at the end of the script or when the script is killed?

Comment: @Flimm you have to trap the signals to run a cleanup function

Answer (score 30):

You can temporarily disable line wrapping by entering this command::

```
tput rmam
```

To restore line wrapping use this command:

```
tput smam
```

Comment: This fixed my issue! More details here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558771/27685

Comment: the issue with this is that is shows the latter part of a line instead of the beginning

Comment: @doplumi for me it shows only the first `$COLUMNS` columns.

Answer (score 22):

Supposing you have the `COLUMNS` variable defined, you can execute

```
tail -f your-app.log | cut -c -$COLUMNS
```

otherwise substitute `$COLUMNS` with the columns width of the terminal, as obtained by `stty -a`.

Comment: Another alternative to `$COLUMNS` (is not immediately updated on `SIGWINCH`, only on the next prompt) and `stty -a` (harder to use in script) is `tput cols`.

Comment: Thanks enzotib. That works, but it trims the line and we are unable to see the end of the long lines. Is is possible to make `cut` behave like `less -S` where the long line are buffered and we are able to see the complete line using the directional keys?

Comment: Uhm, not that simple. I'm thinking of wired solutions as e.g. two separate `screen` windows each with a `tail -f | cut` or a script emulating in some way the `less` behavior. But do not have a solution, at the moment.

Comment: Side-note: cut only counts bytes; unlike `less -S`, it's going to screw up on coloured text, or anything with ANSI escapes. Might screw up Unicode too.

Comment: Yes, `less -S` is more useful with colored text.  You can use `less -S -E` to exit immediately - useful for cutting colored output at $COLUMNS.

Comment: I like this answer best, even if it doesn't adapt to window size changes

Comment: I aliased `alias cut-cols="cut -c -$(tput cols)"`

Comment: -1, should be: cut -c1-$COLUMNS

Comment: @thang: if the first field of list is missed, it default to 1, read the manpage

Comment: cut -c $COLUMNS do not work.
cut -c 1-$COLUMNS work

Answer (score 8):

Two good answers/examples here

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1710/tail-a-log-file-with-long-lines-truncated

```
tail -f logfile.log | cut -b 1-80

tail -f logfile.log | cut -b -$(tput cols)
```

One caveat: at least on the built in terminal on my Mac cut does not seem to handle tab characters very well. It seems it displays them with e.g., 8 spaces but just calculates them as 4 space wide or something like that. In other words, if your terminal is 80 characters wide  and your output contains several tabs per line you must set the width to maybe 60 or something like that. YMMV.

Comment: `cut` only counts bytes. It doesn't handle multi-byte characters well. Nor does it handle codes that set colours in the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

The terminator (http://software.jessies.org/terminator/) terminal emulator allow to not wrap long lines and has horizontal scrolling (but is written in Java).

Comment: How do I enable it? It doesn't seem to work by default.

Comment: As of this writing, horizontal scroll is on by default. Great, cross-platform recommendation. Thanks!

Comment: Please make this answer better by showing how one would enable this feature.  I've searched in Preferences and can't seem to locate this option. FWIW, I'm running `terminator v1.91`.

Comment: @AnthonyK There are two unrelated terminal emulators sharing the name `terminator`, [this one](https://github.com/software-jessies-org/jessies/wiki/Terminator) which gentledevil is referring to and [that one](https://launchpad.net/terminator) which you are using.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of comments which stray from the question.  OP's *question* was

> But now I need to use `tail -f`, and it also line wraps the output. Is it possible to disable line wrap in a bash shell for all the commands?

Some comments were made about the autowrap feature, stating that not all terminals have it.  Perhaps.  But (aside from [terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/), whose developers document no [terminal description](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_T_E_R_M_I_N_A_T_O_R)) all of the examples given were xterm, rxvt and some look-alike or descendent.  Those are all related.

The `+aw` option in `xterm` corresponds to the `autoWrap` resource.  Consulting the manual, it says that

```
   autoWrap (class AutoWrap)
           Specifies  whether  or  not  auto-wraparound should be enabled.
           This is the same as the VT102 DECAWM.  The default is "true".
```

and in [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Pm-h:Ps-=-7.1E67) it says

```
CSI ? Pm h
          ...
          DEC Private Mode Set (DECSET).
            Ps = 7  -> Wraparound Mode (DECAWM).
```

which certainly does not "depend on your choice of terminal", since any terminal with VT100-compatibility supports the feature.  xterm and rxvt do this, for example.  The others do as well.

Whether the feature would be *useful* to OP is debatable.  Suppressing line-wrapping is only one aspect of the problem:

- The shell knows the width of the terminal—but that can be overridden by setting `COLUMNS` to a "large" value.
- Of course that means that applications will spend a lot of time writing on the right-margin (and some, getting it wrong, will start a new line anyway).
- OP probably assumed that the application would scroll left/right to make the wide terminal usable.  (terminator does this — partly — but its other drawbacks cancel that out, except for those who only use the terminal for `cat`'ing a logfile to the screen).
- what OP actually is looking for is a set of tools that can be told to disable line-wrap, especially for viewing logfiles.  If the terminal works well enough for general use, it is irrelevant to the choice of tools which one uses within the terminal.

There are pagers which can do what is needed, e.g., [multitail](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/features.php) which lists in its features

> Line wrapping can be switched off, after that one can scroll to the left/right with the cursor keys

Being ncurses-based, it should work on any of the cited terminals.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few examples on this page piping tail with -f ... from my tests it doesn't work properly, if you really need piping (eg. if you need to pipe something more, like grep) you may use something like:

```
watch -n 1 'tail -n $(($LINES-3)) file.log | cut -c -$COLUMNS'
```

not the best for performance probably but works... else if no extra pipping required you may use something different like:

```
less -S +F file.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below options with `less`. It will disable word wrap and preserve text colors, if specified.
`less -SR +F filename`

Answer (score -1):

vi

inside vi type

```
:set nowrap
```

I beleive there is also a plugin for vi that will give you tail like behaviour.

Answer (score -3):

If you really want to see the full lines you can copy and paste the text into a text editor like Atom or Notepad++ and disable line wraps in there.