# tmux equivalent to GNU screen's :wrap mode

Tags: tmux

I'm a long time screen user trying to make the jump to tmux.  One screen feature I use is the ability to truncate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> `:set wrap` output.  This is especially useful when tailing log files or following compile sessions whose lines are hundreds of characters long.

I've read the `man` page and googled extensively and cannot find an equivalent command, or a viable work-around using shell commands.  The closest I can come up with is piping everything to `less -S` and putting less into "follow" mode.

Answer (score 13):

I have tmux 2.6, and I can run the command `setterm -linewrap off` to have long lines truncated instead of wrapped.

See these answers:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345492
- https://superuser.com/a/600694

Comment: However, this command has nothing to do with tmux. In particular, if you expand a tmux pane to the right, the truncated characters are still gone.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think `tmux` has this feature, [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=200378&atid=973265)?

One pipable workaround that I often use is "cutting" up to and including $COLUMNS:

```
tail -f LOG | cut -c1-$COLUMNS
```

Note that this is not "nowrap", it actually removes the ends of the lines. Also, terminal resizing is not acted upon.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I've tried variations on the theme as well.  I've found "less -eS --follow-name" to be as close as I can get... IF if remember to run that command first.

Comment: You might do a little better with `less +G +F -eS --follow-name`, that will get you directly into tail mode. But you're right, it would be better if the terminal handled the wrapping.

Comment: `+G` is actually redundant.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work with xtail...