# Cut colored text ignoring color tags

Tags: terminal, colors, tmux, cut

My problem is similar to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44122/tmux-equivalent-to-gnu-screens-wrap-mode); I want to use `cut` to simulate a `nowrap` on `tmux`, but my output is colored. I know how many columns I want to keep (50) but I don't know how many color tags will be on the output. Cutting with `cut -c-50` generates all kinds of different output, depending on how many escape characters (color tags) are on each line.

So, summing it up: can I cut the text with a fixed width ignoring the colors, so that I always end up with 50 colored characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
perl -pe 's/^((?:(?>(?:\e\[.*?m)*).){50}).*/$1\e[m/'
```

That assumes ansi-type escape sequences.

Those are with escape sequences like `\e[31m` to set a colour and `\e[m` or `\e[0m` to reset it. Above, we add `\e[m` at the end of each line, but that might not always be desirable depending on the input.

Comment: This works to some extent but has some issues with the last escape sequence until the cut limit exceeds the string length + escape sequences. See [this](http://i.imgur.com/UObmf.png) test run.

Comment: Good point, I've edited my answer.

Comment: This is almost it; however, there's still a small problem. Consider [this example](http://pastie.org/4653245). The input loses the last 'm' of the escape sequence and prints garbage in the end of the output.

Comment: Wonderful. Ran perfectly with a log file of ~30k lines, so I'm considering it done. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me.